# Jssor Slider - random slide selection

Tags: responsive-design, slider, photo

I'm already using Jssor for a responsive navigation slider. I would like to use it to replace a random photo banner div on this same page as well. I know how get two Jssor instances on the same page, but how can I get Jssor to select a random photo from the collection, AND do it on each page load? It has to be responsive too.

If Jssor is overkill for this, just tell me so. But suggestions for a good responsive alternative would of course be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Before you initialize jssor slider, you can generate slides html content dynamically.
That's to say, you can choose photo randomly from collection and then generate slides html code.

there is a case with generated content.
[Jssor slides with generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824898/jssor-slides-with-generated-content)